# Why autohotkey key remapping not working in putty?

Tags: putty, autohotkey

I'm on a windows laptop and a vim user. I've remapped capslock to escape using autohotkey.

I have a putty session, when I press capslock, it's still turning on/off upper case instead of sending escape.

Why??

Comment: Could you post the script you are using? I just tried it with ```CapsLock::Esc``` and it seems to work for me.

Comment: exactly the same script as you post, doesn't work. I find another fork of putty: kitty. in Kitty it work.